# Data not updating properly on i18n lang switch

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, strapi, vue-i18n

On my index page, loading it for the first time returns the correct data I need:

```
index.js

<script>
  export default {
    async asyncData({ store, i18n }) {
      let lang
      if (i18n.locale == "en") lang = 'en'
      if (i18n.locale == "pt") lang = 'pt-PT'
      if (i18n.locale == "fr") lang = 'fr'

      try {
        const services = await (await fetch(`${store.state.apiUrl}/project-categories?populate=*&locale=` + lang)).json()
        const projects = await (await fetch(`${store.state.apiUrl}/projects?populate=*&locale=` + lang)).json()
        const articles = await (await fetch(`${store.state.apiUrl}/articles?populate=*&locale=` + lang)).json()

        console.log(projects.data)
        
        return {
          projects: projects.data,
          articles: articles.data,
          services: services.data
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Returned data in default english looks like this:

```
[                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  {
    id: 1,
    attributes: {
      title: 'Space RTS Game',
      slug: 'space-rts-game',
      intro: 'A Space Real-Time-Strategy MMO Game Project ...',
      body: '',
      subtitle: 'Game Development',
      createdAt: '2022-06-13T15:09:23.144Z',
      updatedAt: '2022-06-16T11:42:58.215Z',
      publishedAt: '2022-06-16T11:42:58.209Z',
      locale: 'en',
      cover: [Object],
      images: [Object],
      localizations: [Object]
    }
  },
  (...)
]
```

But once I switch the lang to fr, the data is returned as observers:

[image: results after switch lang]

Here is the used html for switching lang:

```
<template>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav justify-content-end">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="javascript:void(0)" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          {{ $root.$i18n.locale }}
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <nuxt-link
            v-for="locale in availableLocales"
            :key="locale.code"
            :to="switchLocalePath(locale.code)"
            class="dropdown-item">{{ locale.name }}
          </nuxt-link>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</template>

(...)

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    availableLocales () {
      return this.$i18n.locales.filter(i => i.code !== this.$i18n.locale)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

If I try to copy this (observers) object from my browser console into a text editor, I've got these results which is much more complex (but shows the translated data in french inside):

```
[
    {
        "id": 4,
        "attributes": {
            "title": "Jeu Spatial RTS",
            "slug": "jeu-spatial-rts",
            "intro": "Un projet de jeu MMO de stratégie en temps réel spatial utilisant des ressources basées sur NFT Casper - La plupart des éléments de conception du jeu sont déjà terminés. Le développement commence bientôt...",
            "body": null,
            "subtitle": "Dev. de Jeu",
            "createdAt": "2022-06-16T08:33:39.761Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-06-16T18:09:49.524Z",
            "publishedAt": "2022-06-16T11:44:12.561Z",
            "locale": "fr",
            "cover": {
                "data": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "attributes": {
                        "name": "cover-surface-lg.jpg",
                        "alternativeText": "cover-surface-lg.jpg",
                        "caption": "cover-surface-lg.jpg",
                        "width": 370,
                        "height": 240,
                        "formats": {
                            "thumbnail": {
                                "name": "thumbnail_cover-surface-lg.jpg",
                                "hash": "thumbnail_cover_surface_lg_6b09d070dd",
                                "ext": ".jpg",
                                "mime": "image/jpeg",
                                "path": null,
                                "width": 240,
                                "height": 156,
                                "size": 10.98,
                                "url": "/uploads/thumbnail_cover_surface_lg_6b09d070dd.jpg"
                            }
                        },
                        "hash": "cover_surface_lg_6b09d070dd",
                        "ext": ".jpg",
                        "mime": "image/jpeg",
                        "size": 21.62,
                        "url": "/uploads/cover_surface_lg_6b09d070dd.jpg",
                        "previewUrl": null,
                        "provider": "local",
                        "provider_metadata": null,
                        "createdAt": "2022-06-13T15:19:23.234Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2022-06-13T15:19:23.234Z"
                    }
                }
            },
            "images": {
                "data": null
            },
            "localizations": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "attributes": {
                            "title": "Space RTS Game",
                            "slug": "space-rts-game",
                            "intro": "A Space Real-Time-Strategy MMO Game Project using NFTs Casper based assets - Most of the game design parts are already done. Development starting soon...",
                            "body": "",
                            "subtitle": "Game Development",
                            "createdAt": "2022-06-13T15:09:23.144Z",
                            "updatedAt": "2022-06-16T11:42:58.215Z",
                            "publishedAt": "2022-06-16T11:42:58.209Z",
                            "locale": "en"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "attributes": {
                            "title": "Jogo RTS Espacial",
                            "slug": "jogo",
                            "intro": "Um projeto de jogo MMO de estratégia em tempo real espacial usando recursos baseados em NFTs Casper - A maioria das partes de design de jogos já está pronta. Desenvolvimento começando em breve...",
                            "body": null,
                            "subtitle": "Jogo Dev.",
                            "createdAt": "2022-06-16T08:34:11.701Z",
                            "updatedAt": "2022-06-16T18:10:08.725Z",
                            "publishedAt": "2022-06-16T11:44:18.058Z",
                            "locale": "pt-PT"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    (...)
```

As you can notice, it starts now at id: 4 and page text in my page just disappeared once I switched the lang. I'm a beginner with Nuxt / Vue.Js and would be curious why this is happening and find clues on how to resolve that problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you switch locales with a `router-link` ? You should simply assign the new locale to `$root.$i18n.locale`.

Comment: I need to get new language data from strapi api server and reflect this lang selection in URL. So yes, I'm using a `nuxt-link`. I'm simply following the official i18n nuxt documentation in here https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/lang-switcher/ . Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I doubt `i18n` is aware (or cares about) that you need to fetch your locale messages from Strapi first. Just navigating to a different route probably will not switch the locale automatically for you.

Comment: It does. For example reaching my local url + /fr load the french lang properly. But that occur on first page load, not the lang switching where the vars including the data have to be reset or maybe a new page load is needed. I tried using `this.$nuxt.refresh()` without any changes.

Comment: I guess it's because on first load the page is server-side rendered and the HTML already contains the proper translations. But in order to switch the locale at run time you have to first make an AJAX request to Strapi, then update `$root.$i18n.messages` with the translations, then switch the locale of `$i18n` and only then change the slug in the route (i.e. navigate to the foreign language).